# Connecting web clients to dynamic spawning docker containers

Tags: node.js, docker, nginx

I am writing an online coding site using nodejs. When the user requests, I spawn a docker container to compile and run their code then delete it. After a small amount of time the docker container is stopped and removed.

The executable running inside the container communicates live in real-time with the client browser using a client side javascript library and a specific port opened on the docker container which is by both sides. (For reference I am using this javascript library http://robotwebtools.org/tools.html) This works for a single user.

However, I need a solution for when there are multiple simultaneous users and hence multiple docker containers are simultaneously spawned (due to multiple simultaneous requests) which must be on different ports. I need a way to get the client side javascript code to communicate with the appropriate docker container on unique ports. Note I am looking for a solution for tens of simultaneous users on one machine rather than for massive scaling.  I can think of two ways to do this.

(A) Open a number of public ports, have nodejs spawn the docker container with a unique port, send this unique port to the client side code. I think this would work and be fairly easy to implement. I don't think security would be a problem as the containers are only briefly connected to the ports. However, is there something I am forgetting?

(B) Open only a single public port, have nodejs spawn the docker container with a unique port and have the nodejs listen on the common client port and do the forwarding to the correct docker container port base on some user id? I'm not even sure how I would do this in nodejs? Is there something I could use to do this?

Are either of these appropriate? Or is there another solution? If B is appropriate, how would I identify each user's stream. Note, if relevant, I plan to use nginx for the reverse proxy.

Comment: Wouldn't this be simpler if you just did a `docker run` injecting the code and simply just returning the container output? No need to deal with sockets or anything.

Comment: The communication is live and in real-time. ie you can send information to the executable that it deals with live. I've updated my question with this information.